# how can I make cron jobs keep working even if set_time_limit passed?

Tags: php, cron

we have a Cron Job that runs every minute to do some tasks , sometimes a task takes longer than it should , so what happens is project get killed and data lost ..
how we can run same method every min , and if it takes longer then keep it going not kill it ?

our code is simple :

```
 set_time_limit(60);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 59; ++$i) {
        $this->doStuff();
        sleep(1);
    }


    public function doStuff(){
        if($this->lockCreated()){
            $findNewRecords = db::get_all("select * from **** where **** ")
            if($findNewRecords){
                foreach($findNewRecords as $task){
                $this->handleTask($task)
                }
            }
            $this->releaseLock()();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to let it run longer, remove the time limit. But be aware a new process will run parallel. You could prevent it with [run-one](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/run-one) adding in crontab. This would would make sure only one runs and if a new one is started it will be ignored until the first is finished.

Comment: thanks for reply , will it start directly once the first one finish or it has to wait for another minute till it starts ?

Comment: Simplified summary: Run-One creates a lock mechanism for each task. When a task is run, it creates a lock. It will be removed, when the task is done. When the same task runs again while the lock is active, it won't be started. So it acts like a manager. Example: crontab every 60 seconds. First starts, takes 65 seconds. Second will be ignored (because one is runnig, lock active), third (at next minute) will run (because second finished, lock removed).

Comment: oh .. that will break our website , it is about a web game and it's tasks must be processed every second otherwise it will bug the game , can you help me with something that will keep the game functioning will ?

Comment: Then it is a completely different topic. You should not run a cronjob every second!

Comment: what should I do in that case ?

Comment: This going to be opinion based, because it depends on different strategies you can go. First of all more details are required. Why every second? Must it be exactly 1000ms? What kind of data is processed? How is the processed data accessed? ....

Comment: the game is about attacks and defense , it is time based . every second there might be a new attack that the system should look into it and process it , meaning data is different every second and that is why we run a cron every minute then we loop for the whole 60s

Comment: This information does not really help. How is the data structured? How is it shared between processes? How is client/server communication organized? If that cronjob works, stop using a cronjob at all and make it a permanent running process. Implement the delta time stategy to ensure it runs every 1000ms.

Comment: sorry for that , I am not that an expert , so I am not familiar with that strategy . as for the game , what is happening right now is the following : every minute a cron task will work and call a page that will loop for 60 times , in each loop it will search in db for new records that have end time = now or less . if it does find any , it will start processing them , such as if it finds an attack coming it will process the attack the create a result report for the players , I edit the post with extra code example